# unable to add a new user to the mongodb database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js, google-oauth

I need help guys!!! I want to add a new User to the database but I am unable to. I am connected to Mongodb server (working with Atlas). My console.log() shows that I am importing the model User into passport-setup.js file (where I want to add a new user from). I am new to Mongodb.

App.js where I connect to mongodb server via Atlas (importing connection string from a different file:

```
mongoose.connect(keys.mongodb.dbURI, () => {
    console.log('Successfully connected to mongodb...');
})
```

user-model.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
    username: String,
    googleId: String
})

const User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

passport-setup.js:

```
const passport = require('passport');
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20');
const keys = require('./keys.js');
const User = require('./db/models/user-model.js');
console.log('inside passport setup')
console.log('User:', User);


passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy({
        // options for the strategy
        callbackURL: '/auth/google/redirect',
        clientID: keys.google.clientID,
        clientSecret: keys.google.clientSecret
    }, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
        // passport callback function
        console.log('passport callback function fired')
        console.log(profile)
        new User({
            username: profile.displayName,
            googleId: profile.id
        }).save().then((newUser) => {
            console.log('new user created: ' + newUser);
        })
    })
)
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I am getting no error. I wish I was, but there is nothing

Comment: can you please try catching the error in the save function of the model

Comment: probably should separate code from permissions for the moment. log in manually and verify your user/pw role allows adding a user.  If so - then it is code...if not then is your mongo role.